# What is this connection on the air intake right before the turbo?

Tags: diesel, air-intake, citroen

This is the engine bay of a Citroën C5. I would like to know what the connection indicated by the red square is for. I removed the air duct once to check the EGR valve and there was a little oil inside the connector which I think is weird for an air intake.
[image: picture of engine bay with a red square around the subject]

Comment: I don't know for sure, but would bet it is connected to the PCV ... it's pretty common for the PCV to draw a small amount of oil from the engine, which ultimately ends up in the intake tract. This is pretty true of most any engine. A lot of people will get separators which goes in line from the PCV to intake, which gives a "quiet place" for the oil to drop out of the air and allow the crankcase gases to pass on into the engine.